# Documentation of Autodesk Inventor integration with Salesforce

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to integrate Autodesk Inventor in our Salesforce Application, so I am not getting proper documentation for which I can refer and proceed further to integrate it.

So, can you kindly provide me with the documentation or steps which we can use to integrate with salesforce and which includes the complete procedure to integrate, and even the sample codes in apex language.

Thanks,
Ansar

Comment: could you clarify whether you wanted to embed Forge Viewer inside SalesForce application, in order to load Inventor model? I do not see we have a demo sample. probably similar to embed viewer inside Sharepoint https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/sharepoint-online-integration

Comment: if what you are asking is another question, please feel free to provide more information to help us know the context